# Manga where the MC is an ex-hero and joined the demon army

Tags: story-identification, manga

The Main Character (MC) wants to join the demon army and he fought one of the demon generals as a test to see if his worthy to join.

After they fought, she got defeated. The demon general which is a type of beast-girl fell in love with the MC and wanted to marry him because she likes strong men.

I don't remember if the manga is R-18 but it's not censored.

I read it 5 years ago, it had a few chapters but I think it has way more now after I forgot about it

It's a typical overpowered MC manga, but it's pretty interesting

I've tried to see if " i'm quitting heroing " is the manga i've been looking for but it isn't the right one

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "I'm Quitting Heroing" isn't a match? It seems to match up on the details you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is *[The Another World Demon King's Successor](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/suteishi-yuusha-maou-no-shita-de-restart)*, identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267765). It is from 2020 so the date doesn't quite match up.

> Asato Kanami who was summoned as a hero to another world Istalia. To stop the war between the demons and humans. It is said that he was summoned by Anna, the saint of the Kingdom of Elshnon. After a year of war, Asato finally challenges the Demon King Lione. Just when he thought the battle was over, his summoner Anna attacked him and the Demon King. Asato who survived the attack and was protected by the Demon King. What is the future path for the hero betrayed by humans...!?

Similar to I’m Quitting Heroing, the main character is a hero that stops being a hero (due to a betrayal shown in the first chapter) and joins the demon queen's army.

Unlike I’m Quitting Heroing, this manga is sexually explicit, with the protagonist having sex with a maid in the second chapter.

There is also a scene where he is challenged by a beastwoman general of the demon queen's army, defeats her, and she proposes marriage.

[image: Beast woman introduces herself as a general]   [image: Marriage after victory]

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *[I’m Quitting Heroing](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/im-quitting-heroing)*, a completed manga from 2018.

> After saving the world, the strongest hero Leo became someone who is not wanted in the peaceful human world. He was too strong. Exiled, **he seeks a job at the Demon King's Army**, which he had defeated and needs to be rebuilt. The Army had many problems: too much work, financial troubles, etc. Leo starts to make things better using his power. Leo encounters Echidna again, and asks her why she invaded the human world.

The first chapter is mostly a flashback but covers all the details within the question. The main character goes to the demon queen - after he defeated her army - and asks for a job.

[image: Interviewing for job with the demon army]

He does not get it and is thrown out.

The story cuts to him casually chatting with the queen's four top generals, and reminiscing about when he fought and defeated them all when he was still a hero. One of the four is a young beastwoman, who proclaims her desire to marry him since he's strong.

[image: Defeated beastwoman wants to marry the protagonist]